# Redirect Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Прописываю в роутах такой код для `'middleware' => ['web']`, не работает. Есть ли еще варианты запрета доступа к странице для гостей?

```
Route::get('/page', function () {
            return redirect('404');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `auth` middleware для того чтобы закрыть доступ для гостей, если хотите закрыть доступ для авторизованный используйте `guest middleware`, к примеру вот так:

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['auth'], function () {
  //
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант:

```
Route::get('profile', function () {

})->middleware('auth');
```

Второй вариант в конструкторе контроллера:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```